# JavaFX - using FillTransition and TranslateTransition misplaces the object

Tags: javafx, transition

So I have a couple of `Rectangle` objects of different sizes, named `r1` and `r2`, that initially appear in the dead center of the screen. They have different colors (say one is red and the other blue) and the smaller one is placed on top of the larger one, so even when they are stacked in the center, the two are still distinguishable. I wanted them to move around and return to their original positions, and thus used `TranslateTransition` as follows:

```
tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(20000), button1);
tt1.setByX(100);   // moves 100 pixels to the right
tt1.setByY(-100);   // moves 100 pixels down
tt1.setCycleCount(20);   // oscillates 20 times
tt1.setAutoReverse(true);

tt2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(20000), button2);
tt2.setByX(-100);   // moves 100 pixels to the left
tt2.setByY(100);   // moves 100 pixels up
tt2.setCycleCount(20);   // oscillates 20 times
tt2.setAutoReverse(true);
```

During their movement, however, if any of `r1` and `r2` is pressed by a `MouseEvent`, I would like them to disappear for a few seconds (say 5 seconds) and come back alive again. Using the fact the background color is completely black, I used `FillTransition` to achieve that effect:

```
FillTransition ft1 = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(5000), r1, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
FillTransition ft2 = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(5000), r2, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
```

By converting the `Rectangle`s from `Color.BLACK` to `Color.BLACK` for 5 seconds, it gives an effect that the buttons have disappeared for 5 seconds. Also, I have the following `setOnMouseClicked` on `r1` and `r2` so they can disappear when a user input is made:

```
r1.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent t) -> {
    ft1.play();
});
r2.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent t) -> {
    ft2.play();
});
```

After the two objects have disappeared for 5 seconds, they must reappear in the center, as they did in the beginning, and repeat the same oscillating motion using `tt1` and `tt2`, which I achieved with `setOnFinished` on `ft1` and `ft2`:

```
ft1.setOnFinished((ActionEvent event) -> {
    r1.setFill(color1);   // restore the original color
    tt1.play();
});
ft2.setOnFinished((ActionEvent event) -> {
    r2.setFill(color2);   // restore the original color
    tt2.play();
});
```

The problem is, however, when `r1` and `r2` reappear, they are positioned not at the center, but rather at the location from which they last disappeared - in other words, the location of their rebirth is where they were at during the last `TranslateTransition` when a user's `MouseEvent` is detected. I have tried to modify this by using `r1.setX(centerX)` and `r1.setY(centerY)`, where `centerX` and `centerY` are the original center coordinates used in the beginning, but it could not fix the problem. In fact, when I used `r1.getX()`, the returned value equaled the original `centerX` value even when it was conspicuous that `r1` was not placed in the center. This gave me a suspicion that `TranslateTransition` performs its duty without altering the actual `getX()` values. I have also thought of using `ParallelTransition` somehow on `TranslateTransition` and `FillTransition`, so `tt1` could finish while `ft1` takes effect, but since then `ft1` would start running when `tt1` has already been running for some time, it would not provide a feasible solution.

So my question is, if an object's `TranslateTransition` is interrupted in the middle, how do I restore the object's "original" coordinate, not where the object was last left off when `TranslateTransition` was interrupted?

p.s. I want to avoid creating new `Rectangle` objects every time a `MouseEvent` is detected, because that means all `TranslateTransition` and `FillTransition` linked to `r1` and `r2` must be recreated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample Solution**

Run the program, the rectangle will start moving.  Click on the rectangle and it will disappear momentarily.  Shortly after it has disappeared, the rectangle will re-appear at its original start location and start moving along its original trajectory.

[image: sample]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Pauser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(
                50, 150, 30, 30
        );

        final TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                r1
        );
        tt1.setFromX(0);    // start at the layout origin for the node
        tt1.setFromY(0);    //
        tt1.setByX(100);    // moves 100 pixels to the right
        tt1.setByY(-100);   // moves 100 pixels down
        tt1.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
        tt1.setAutoReverse(true);
        tt1.play();

        final PauseTransition pt1 = new PauseTransition(
                Duration.seconds(1)
        );
        pt1.setOnFinished(event -> {
            tt1.playFromStart();
            r1.setVisible(true);
        });

        r1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            r1.setVisible(false);
            tt1.stop();
            r1.setTranslateX(0);
            r1.setTranslateY(0);
            pt1.play();
        });

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new Group(r1),
                        200, 200
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This just solves your problem for one rectangle.  You can stick the solution in a loop to handle multiple rectangles.

**Observations**

1. A [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is used rather than a [FillTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FillTransition.html) and the visibility of the node is set to false while the pause is running.  With a FillTransition the user can still click on the node, even though a node filled with the background color cannot be visibly distinguished from the background.  So a FillTransition is probably undesirable.
2. fromX/fromY properties are set for the translate transition otherwise if you stop and run it from the start it will just use the current translateX/translateY values of the node rather than the origin values of 0/0 which is what you want.
3. While the node is not visible, there is no need to keep running the TranslateTransition, so the transition is stopped for that duration.
4. When the translate transition is stopped, it leaves the translateX/translateY co-ordinates at wherever they are currently set for the last animation frame.  So a manual call to set translateX/translateY to 0/0 is added.
5. After the pause transition is complete, a request is made to play the translate transition from the start rather than wherever it was previously paused or stopped.

**Understanding Transformations**

A node's position on the screen is based on transformations applied to its layout position.  The layout position is maintained in the node's layoutX/layoutY properties.  But if you apply a translate transformation to a node (as you are implicitly doing in a TranslateTransition), then the node's screen position will be [layoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty--)+[translateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty--) / [layoutY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty--)+[translateY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateYProperty--).

**Background Study**

1. Read the [Node documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), in particular the sections on transformations and bounding rectangles.
2. Try out this [layout bounds demonstration](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960) to help understand the concepts.

> So the key was using setFromX and setFromY to start from the original coordinate.

It was also key to set manually set the translateX/translateY values to 0/0.  If this was not done, the node would flash at its last translated position before starting to move from the origin position.  I think this is because there is a frame delay from when you request the animation to start and when it actually starts and uses the fromX/fromY co-ordinates of 0/0.  Which is kind of a strange behavior.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. So the key was using ```setFromX``` and ```setFromY``` to start from the original coordinate. Yeah, I chose ```FillTransition``` precisely because of the reason you specified - the button was still visible and your solution solves the problem. To prevent a further user input while it is black, I used a boolean flag which gets unset/set before disappearing/reappearing. Thanks for the elaborate solution.

Comment: Setting fromX/fromY was part of the solution, but setting translateX/translateY to 0/0 was also important as explained in an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Hopefully it good approach. There could be new class to create `extends rectangle` with events and transitions in it. This is just sample for two `rectangles`.

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle (100, 40, 120, 120);
        rect1.setArcHeight(42);
        rect1.setArcWidth(42);
        rect1.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        TranslateTransition tt1; 
        tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect1);
        tt1.setByX(200);
        tt1.setByY(-200);
        tt1.setCycleCount(2);
        tt1.setAutoReverse(true);
        tt1.play();

        rect1.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect1);
                ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                ft.setToValue(0.0);
                ft.play();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        tt1.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                tt1.play();
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect1);
                ft.setToValue(1.0);
                ft.play();
            }
        });

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle (100, 40, 80, 80);
        rect2.setArcHeight(42);
        rect2.setArcWidth(42);
        rect2.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);

        TranslateTransition tt2; 
        tt2= new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(6000), rect2);
        tt2.setByX(-200);
        tt2.setByY(200);
        tt2.setCycleCount(2);
        tt2.setAutoReverse(true);
        tt2.play();

        rect2.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect2);
                ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                ft.setToValue(0.0);
                ft.play();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        tt2.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                tt2.play();
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect2);
                ft.setToValue(1.0);
                ft.play();
            }
        });

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```